# How does Voldemort get back to Albania?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

In the 1st Harry Potter, at the end it's revealed that Quirrell ran into Voldemort in Albania, where he possessed him. At the end, Voldemort leaves Quirrell, and he dies. Since Voldemort was still a spirit, and not able to hold a wand, how does he get back to Albania?

In book Three we learn that

> "He sought me in the country where it had long been rumored I was hiding . . . helped, of course, by the rats he met along the way. Wormtail has a curious affinity with rats, do you not, Wormtail? His filthy little friends told him there was a place, deep in an Albanian forest, that they avoided, where small animals like themselves had met their deaths by a dark shadow that possessed them. . . ."

How does he make it back to Albania? And why didn't Dumbledore stop him from leaving Hogwarts?

Comment: How did he get there the first time?

Comment: I assume he traveled using animals. I doubt a death eater helped him

Comment: So why couldn't he do the same thing the second time?

Comment: I thought maybe he could have traveled using animals again, but he was in the middle of hogwarts next to dumbledore, the only wizard he feared, when he left quirrells body. So I guess another part of my question is why didn't dumbledore stop him

Comment: I think he was able to travel around while discorporate, i.e., as a "dark shadow".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## He could travel withour wand or human body.

The Dark Lord didn’t need a wand or a human body to travel. When he’s first ripped from his body, the Dark Lord’s incorporeal form appears in the Potters’ house next to Harry’s crib, and he decides he must hide himself far from the house. He successfully left the Potters’ house though that point, he was unable to hold a wand and lacked any human to possess, so he can travel without having either.

> “*He pointed the wand very carefully into the boy’s face: he wanted to see it happen, the destruction of this one, inexplicable danger. The child began to cry: it had seen that he was not James. He did not like it crying, he had never been able to stomach the small ones’ whining in the orphanage –*
>
> ‘Avada Kedavra!’
>
> *And then he broke: he was nothing, nothing but pain and terror, and he must hide himself, not here in the rubble of the ruined house, where the child was trapped and screaming, but far away … far away …”* 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 17 (Bathilda’s Secret)*</sup></sub>

It’s never specified exactly *how* he traveled, but it seems likely he could have traveled as an incorporeal being, since other types of incorporeal being, like ghosts, can travel. The Dark Lord tells the Death Eaters that he settled in a faraway place and doesn’t mention that he could possess animals until after that, which may imply his ability to possess animals wasn’t related to his ability to travel.

> “I remember only forcing myself, sleeplessly, endlessly, second by second, to exist … I settled in a faraway place, in a forest, and I waited … surely, one of my faithful Death Eaters would try and find me … one of them would come and perform the magic I could not, to restore me to a body … but I waited in vain …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, he says that he was little better off possessing animals than he was as pure spirit, which implies that there wasn’t much advantage to possessing. That further implies that it’s unlikely that he was only able to travel while possessing animals, since the ability to travel would likely be considered a decent advantage over existing as pure spirit if he was unable to travel that way.

> “Only one power remained to me. I could possess the bodies of others. But I dared not go where other humans were plentiful, for I knew that the Aurors were still abroad and searching for me. I sometimes inhabited animals – snakes, of course, being my preference – but I was little better off inside them than as pure spirit, for their bodies were ill-adapted to perform magic … and my possession of them shortened their lives; none of them lasted long …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

Of the, he also would have had the option to travel while possessing animals, so he’d have had two options available to him for traveling without a wand or a human body.